# How can I draw and edit shape using Xamarin forms?

Tags: image, xamarin, vector

I want to build a simple Xamarin app that can draw shapes with editing handles. I can then drag and drop the handles to edit the shapes. This can be done with Syncfusion image editor controls but the shapes I wanted are not available.

Can anybody give me some clue about what should I do? Or point me to an open-source project?
[Shape examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McXte.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/

Comment: I'm not aware of any example of a shape editor. So you'll have to learn to draw shapes (Jason's link), then you'll have to learn about detecting user moving finger on screen (maybe google `xamarin forms user move point`). Then you'll have to combine what you've learned. If you get stuck, then come back and post the minimum amount of code to show the detail you are stuck on. See [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). ALSO there are **paint** examples that may help: google `xamarin forms paint example`. You'll see `skiasharp` mentioned; I use that.

Comment: Found relevant sources: [github xamarin/KimonoDesigner](https://github.com/xamarin/KimonoDesigner). Manipulate SkiaSharp shapes in c# using xamarin. Note that this uses SkiaSharp shapes, rather than XForms shapes. That is how I would do it; SkiaSharp is a more extensive API than XF shapes. To use Skia in XF, use [nuget SkiaSharp.Views.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms/). Create an SKCanvasView.

Comment: I downloaded KimonoDesigner but can't make it run. Many dependencies are not supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

SkiaSharp is a 2D graphics system for .NET and C# powered by the open-source Skia graphics engine that is used extensively in Google products. You can use SkiaSharp in your Xamarin.Forms applications to draw 2D vector graphics, bitmaps, and text.

You can refer to the tutorials in the following link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/

Comment: I looked at SkiaSharp before I posted this question but I didn't find any facility for editing. I know the WPF library has thumb and adorners for editing but didn't anything similar in Skiasharp.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, maybe you can check the imageEditor https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/image-editor/shapes

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did go to Synfusion imageEditor but it hadn't got all the shapes I wanted and I couldn't build my own shapes with the control.

Comment: maybe you can do it with gestures  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch